# EDS_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED on Canon t2i rebel with EDSDK 2.11

Tags: c++, edsdk

Wondering if anyone has ever had this problem or might know how to resolve...I'm getting EDS_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED on a Canon t2i rebel with EDSDK 2.11 when I call EdsOpenSession(camera).

The odd thing is that I have the example code that came with the SDK which compiles and runs fine, and it interfaces with my camera just fine.  All of the code I've written has been bare bones with relevant lines copied from the original working example, and I'm now banging my head against a wall.  My code, minimized without error notifications is as follows:

```
EdsError     err = EDS_ERR_OK;
EdsCameraListRef cameraList = NULL;
EdsCameraRef camera = NULL;
EdsUInt32    count = 0; 

EdsInitializeSDK();
EdsGetCameraList(&cameraList);
EdsGetChildCount(cameraList, &count);
EdsGetChildAtIndex(cameraList , 0 , &camera);   

EdsDeviceInfo deviceInfo;
EdsGetDeviceInfo(camera , &deviceInfo); 
EdsRelease(cameraList);

err=EdsOpenSession(camera);
//err returns EDS_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED here
```

This example is also in line with the Canon SDK documentation.

Comment: Sorry, solved.  Not sure how I messed it up, but the lib and some dll files associated with the EDSDK were outdated.

Comment: So what Exactly did you do because i am getting the same error and i am using SDK version 2.4 with Rebel T3 can you please help.